# How to make a lock screen which prevents home, back, or overView press?

Tags: android

My intention is to make a Lock screen Application.

I already tried all available answers. If someone who did implement this kind of app, can help me then all the better.

In other lock screen Application home,back,overView press working but they not showing it. they are only persistently showing there there lock screen. 
they are asking permission for Draw over other app for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide navigation bar like this:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Comment: that can only remove status bar

Comment: check my edited answer based on immersive mode https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: I also tried that by doing that system navigation can be come back by Up swipe.

Comment: It is not possible to hide navigation bar permanently without root devices.

Comment: I don't want to hide it, I want to achieve result as any lock application .

Comment: You can find lock screen app in github here : https://github.com/topics/lockscreen?l=java

Comment: I also Tried all of them too , I can categorise that list into three type. 1) layout
2)lock screen that can open after lock (not dealing with current problem)
3)https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker that can't be use in new Api because can't overly dialog over lock screen